# All administrator page login are not working and showing "Service Unavailable"

Tags: mysql, php, wordpress, hosting, joomla

Let assume I have websites aaa.com, bbb.com and ccc.com

aaa.com - working.
aaa.com/about - working.
aaa.com/services - working.
aaa.com/administrator - **Showing the below error message.**

> **"Service Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."**

Similary bbb.com/administrator
         ccc.com/administrator also showing the same message.

I have checked **server error logs** and there was no error logged in the server error log file.

Only administrator pages are showing this error after enter the credentials. I have tried to find solution for this in many forums, But all answer where useless and not working.

We are using : Strato Server WE are using Wordpress, Joomla for websites. We are maintaining more than 4 websites.

Th problem is all websites administrator pages are showing the error
" "Service Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."

Let me know if anyone can find solution and help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Does any knows solution for this issue ?

Comment: I am waiting for answers.....

Comment: Is there no one to look into this ??

Answer (score 0):

What in your apache/nginx configuration files? I assume you have a rule to filter `/administrator` paths. If you are using apache it is also better to check `.htaccess` file at the roots of your project.